# On reload of page, mvp4g history mechanism fails

Tags: java, gwt, mvp4g

I have implemented a history mechanism for my mvp4g project. When I traverse through the pages, I can see the url also getting changed. But on reload of any page other than home page, always home page gets displayed instead of the desired page?

This is my implementation:

```
    @History(type = HistoryConverterType.SIMPLE)
public class CustomHistoryConverter implements HistoryConverter<AppEventBus> {

    private CustomEventBus eventBus;

    @Override
    public void convertFromToken(String historyName, String param, CustomEventBus eventBus) {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
        eventBus.dispatch(historyName, param);
    }

    public String convertToToken(String eventName, String name) {
        return name;
    }

    public String convertToToken(String eventName) {
        return eventName;
    }

    public String convertToToken(String eventName, String name, String type) {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isCrawlable() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and event bus related code :

```
    @Events(startPresenter=PageOnePresenter.class,historyOnStart=true)
public interface CustomEventBus extends EventBusWithLookup {

    @Start
    @Event(handlers = PageOnePresenter.class)
    void start();

    @InitHistory
    @Event(handlers = PageOnePresenter.class)
    void init();

    @Event(handlers = PageTwoPresenter.class, name = "page2", historyConverter = CustomHistoryConverter.class)
    void getPageTwo();

    @Event(handlers = PageThreePresenter.class, name = "page3", historyConverter=CustomHistoryConverter.class)
    void getPageThree();

    @Event(handlers=PageOnePresenter.class, name = "page1", historyConverter=CustomHistoryConverter.class)
    void getPageOne();

    @Event(handlers=PageOnePresenter.class)
    void setPageTwo(HistoryPageTwoView view);

    @Event(handlers=PageOnePresenter.class)
    void setPageThree(HistoryPageThreeView view);
 }
```

Comment: Which version of mvp4g are you using?

Comment: 1.5.2 version of mvp4g I am using @ElHoss

Comment: Can you provide the url token, which is used to reload the page and fails?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8888/demoApp#page2?page2, but later when reloaded it again gets change to http://127.0.0.1:8888/demoApp#page1?page1.

Comment: Does the event "page2" really has no parameters?

Comment: Yeah, I haven't provided any parameters for now. Should I need to provide?

Comment: On reload, onModuleLoad method is called of mvp4g. So do I need to add some extra logic for history over there too?

Comment: No, you don't need to provide any parameters. But you HistoryConverter will not work, if you have one.

Comment: Ok I havent, and what about onModuleLoad method?

Comment: No, but got it ...

Answer (score 1):

The HistoryConverter needs to be improved.

In fact, that the event has no parameter, you should return an empty string. Update the HistoryConverter that it looks like that:

```
@History(type = HistoryConverterType.SIMPLE)
public class CustomHistoryConverter implements HistoryConverter<AppEventBus> {

    private CustomEventBus eventBus;

    @Override
    public void convertFromToken(String historyName, String param, CustomEventBus eventBus) {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
        // TODO handle the param in cases where you have more than one parameter
        eventBus.dispatch(historyName, param);
    }

    public String convertToToken(String eventName, String name) {
        return name;
    }

    public String convertToToken(String eventName) {
        return "";
    }

    public String convertToToken(String eventName, String name, String type) {
        return name - "-!-" type;
    }

    public boolean isCrawlable() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Actually, I had a history defined for the event which had @InitHistory annotation, which on removal solved the problem!